# How to fix IIS Express (Google Chrome) error where the code stops a few seconds after clicking run?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, google-chrome, iis-express

When I click on the green play button that says IIS Express (Google Chrome) Visual Studio starts and then stops the code within 2-5 seconds.

I have cleaned, rebuilt, and restarted both visual studio and my computer.

I have a C# back end code that when it runs it normally opens a Chrome window with a swagger page of my controllers. Today it started normally, the diagnostic tools opens on the right of the screen, and after a few seconds it quits out and the window returns to normal. I get no errors and have nothing in the output.

EDIT: Fixed it by deleting the applicationhost.config file.

Comment: Post an answer and accept it. That's how Stack Overflow works.

Comment: Thanks, added it as an answer. Will mark it tomorrow after the wait period.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by deleting the applicationhost.config file.